# Strange behaviour running a node on Google Cloud

Tags: node, bootstrapping

When trying to bootstrap a node in a VM on Google Cloud Platform I see the performance running fine for approximately 30 minutes before it completely tails off.

You can see this from the graphs below which show the CPU + IO for the past day on the instance.  You can clearly see the point at which I start the tezos-node as everything spikes up.  CPU goes up to 20% - about 80% of a single CPU (I guess Tezos doesn't make use of multiple CPUs) and the IOPS steadliy climbs up, peaking at about 3,500 IOPS or 16MB/S.

However after 30 minutes everything just tanks to the point where it takes several seconds for each block to validate.  Not sure what's going on here.

This is a n1-highmem-4 instance (4 vCPUs, 26 GB memory), although I have seen the same behaviour on various other instance type in GCP. And can be reproduced very easily on any instance type I have tried.

This one has been running for about 17 hours now and only got to block BL6SwDDDhqHkQEpfGWVBFBZ6LX1Byg4eibHSEvQbmS3bL7Z8b89 (3-Aug)

[image: CPU + Network IO]

[image: Disk I/O]

**Update**

After the comment about disk size I provisioned a bigger SSD (200GB) and this appears to resolve the problem.   Will do some [research](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/performance) to see what the minimum disk size is to achieve the consistent 3,500 IOPS that Tezos seems to need.

Comment: Describe the disk? Did you try increasing the disk size (and throughput) to see if the disk is the bottleneck?

Comment: Make sure you are not running out of inodes. `df -i`

Comment: @Tom seems the disk is the issue alright, reading up a bit on GCP the disk performance increases linearly with size.  The node in the question was the default one (I had provisioned a local SSD but forgot to mount it!).  I've provisioned a 200GB SSD and the node is humming along nicely at approx 3,500 IOPS for the last 12 hours

Comment: @Tom nice! Feel free to hit "answer your own question" and write up the correct answer here - so your question get's answered and other people can find the solution more easily 